# Natural Deduction Prove ∀x¬P (x)

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, natural-deduction

$\begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \vee \forall x \neg P(x) \quad premise 
\\ \exists xQ(x) \rightarrow \neg P(x) \quad premise \\ \forall xQ(x) \quad premise
\\\hline \begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \quad assumption
\\\hline \vdots \quad 
\\ \forall x\neg P(x) \quad \end{array}
\\\begin{array}{|l} \forall x\neg P(x) \quad assumption \\\hline \end{array} 
\\ \forall x \neg P(x) \quad \vee elim\\ \end{array}$

Am I on the right path to solving this or how should I be thinking about it? I think I may have strayed from the path in trying to use $\vee$ elim, just didn't see a different path to take.

Comment: Correct : you have to use $\lor$-elim on 1st premise : one of the two sub-proof is trivial. For the second one (assumption $\forall Px$) we use also other premises. If all are $P$s and all are $Q$s, all are $P \land Q$s, contradicting the fact taht there is something that is noot $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So for the first subproof would I have to use a $\rightarrow$ elim and a $\forall$ intro to get the to $\forall x \neg P(x)$ there?  For the second subproof I see that it is trivial, but what then would I have to use in order to obtain the result? Since it is already what I am trying to prove.

Comment: The second sub-proof is already there : delete the "dots" and it's done. The first one is more tricky...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What would I state as my reasoning to end that proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you have an existential and a universal in the premises.  Assume a witness for the existance and see what happens under the assumption of $\forall x~P(x)$.

$\begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \vee \forall x \neg P(x) \quad premise 
\\ \exists xQ(x) \rightarrow \neg P(x) \quad premise \\ \forall xQ(x) \quad premise
\\\hline \begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \quad assumption\\\hline \begin{array}{|l}[c]~Q(c)\to\neg P(c)\quad assumption\\\hline \vdots \end{array}\\\ldots \qquad existential~elimination \\ \vdots
\\ \forall x\neg P(x) \quad \end{array}
\\\begin{array}{|l} \forall x\neg P(x) \quad assumption
\\\hline  \end{array} 
\\ \forall x \neg P(x) \quad \vee elim\\ \end{array}$

Comment: Do you mean something more like this?    $\begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \vee \forall x \neg P(x) \quad premise 
\\ \exists xQ(x) \rightarrow \neg P(x) \quad premise \\ \forall xQ(x) \quad premise
\\\hline \begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \quad assumption\\\hline \begin{array}{|l}[c]~Q(c)\to\neg P(c)\quad assumption
\\\hline \vdots \quad
\\ \forall x\neg P(x) \quad \end{array}
\\ \forall x\neg P(x) \quad \exists Elim \end{array}
\\\begin{array}{|l} \forall x\neg P(x) \quad assumption
\\\hline  \end{array} 
\\ \forall x \neg P(x) \quad \vee elim\\ \end{array}$ assume witness? Whats that

Comment: $\begin{array}{|l}\forall xP(x)\vee\forall x\neg P(x)\quad premise
\\\exists xQ(x)\rightarrow\neg P(x)\quad premise
\\\forall xQ(x)\quad premise
\\\hline\begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \quad assumption
\\\hline\begin{array}{|l} [c] Q(c) \rightarrow \neg P(c)\quad assumption
\\\hline Q(x) \quad\forall Elim ~3
\\\neg P(c) \quad\rightarrow Elim ~5,6
\\(\forall x)\neg P(x)\quad\forall intro ~7\end{array}
\\\forall x\neg P(x) \quad\exists Elim ~4-7\end{array}
\\\begin{array}{|l} \forall x\neg P(x) \quad assumption\\\hline\end{array}
\\\forall x\neg P(x)\quad\vee Elim ~4-9,10\\\end{array}$

Comment: No. @AndrewRyan .  You cannot use $\forall$ introduction.  Use $\forall$ *elimination* on the assumption to derive a contradiction.  From a contradiction you can then derive ...

Comment: $\begin{array}{|l}\forall xP(x)\vee\forall x\neg P(x)\quad premise
\\\exists xQ(x)\rightarrow\neg P(x)\quad premise
\\\forall xQ(x)\quad premise
\\\hline\begin{array}{|l} \forall xP(x) \quad assumption
\\\hline\begin{array}{|l} [c] Q(c) \rightarrow \neg P(c)\quad assumption
\\\hline Q(x) \quad\forall Elim ~3
\\\neg P(c) \quad\rightarrow Elim ~5,6
\\ P(x) \quad\forall Elim ~4
\\\vdots\end{array}
\\\forall x\neg P(x) \quad\exists Elim ~4-7\end{array}
\\\begin{array}{|l} \forall x\neg P(x) \quad assumption\\\hline\end{array}
\\\forall x\neg P(x)\quad\vee Elim ~4-9,10\\\end{array}$

Comment: where to go from here? How are we going to get to $\forall x \neg P(x)$?

Comment: Eliminate the universal to the assumed witness ($c$), thereby deriving $P(c)$.  Use negation elimination to derive a contradiction (aka *falsity*, $\bot$).  Now, *what rule* may you use to derive *what* from a contradiction?

Comment: The only rule that I know of (from my book) is to use PBC (Proof By Contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

What you did so far is correct, and you only have to fill in the "..."s in your subproofs.

The second subproof is easy: You already got your conclusion $\forall x \neg P(x)$ as an assumption -- just reiterate (R) that line and you're done.

As for the first subproof, the idea is to **derive a contradiction between $\neg P(a)$ for some individual $a$ in the second premise -- of which we know there is an instance, since we are given $\forall x Q(x)$ -- and the universal claim $\forall x P(x)$**:
Assume $Q(a) \to \neg P(a)$ for an arbitrary individual $a$. By the third premise $\forall x Q(x)$ we know by universal instantiation ($\forall\!$ E) that $Q$ indeed holds of $a$. By modus ponens ($\to\!$ E), we can conclude $\neg P(a)$. But this contradicts the proposition that $P(a)$, which we get out of the assumption $\forall x P(x)$ by $\forall\!$ E, so we get a contradiction $\bot$. From this contradiction we are allowed to conclude anything thanks to ex falso quodlibet ($\bot$) -- conveniently, we can choose $\forall x \neg P(x)$ as the next conclusion. Since we were able to derive this conclusion under the assumption that $Q(a) \to \neg P(a)$ holds for some individual $a$, and by the second premise we know that at least one such individual does exist, we may apply $\exists\!$ E on the existential formula and the subproof, and thereby discharge the assumption $Q(a) \to \neg P(a)$ to conclude $\forall x \neg P(x)$ for sure.

[image]